# How do you start ffserver when the server starts up?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, daemon, ffserver

I have ffmpeg's ffserver installed on Ubuntu but want to start it as a daemon feeding it a config file when the server boots, how do I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update-rc.d command to do the same

> sudo update-rc.d ffserver defaults

Check the man pages of update-rc.d for more details

Comment: Only ffserver does not install anything under `/etc/init.d`, at least not on Ubuntu.